# Is it recommended to deploy MySQL database in kubernetes with one pod or more pods in production?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, amazon-eks

Is it recommended to deploy MySQL database in kubernetes with one pod or more pods in the production?

What are the advantages and disadvantages if we deploy MySQL database k8s production.

1. Should we have only one pod with persistent volume.
2. is any chances to have issue with data read and write when we use multiple MySQL pods in production.

Comment: If you want high availability, you'll need to deploy several replicas of MySQL.  I'd recommend looking at something like https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mariadb which handles most of this for you.

Comment: My advice is, if you're still unexperienced (even if you experienced) with k8s and databases as well, you actually don't want to host it by yourself. The cloud provider are giving you a good service to do it for you. And they are not so expensive. They maintain it for you and having a good backup solutions. I recommend to go with this, and it gives you more time to focus and develop your apps. (my personal experience)

Answer (score 0):

Having one database pod in production would lead to single point of failure. You need to deploy the database with high availability using multiple replicas and automatic failover if you consider running databases in kubernetes. good to add database backup and restore features to the pod image for recovery purpose in case the database needs to be restored from   an old backup copy.

consider the below helm charts for mysql deployment in kubernetes container platform
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mariadb